# How do you concatenate strings using CTE in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

Using CTE or Common Table Expressions, how do you concatenate strings across multiple rows.

Comment: Why do you need to do this with a CTE? [There are better ways](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) (look at the perf of the CTE approach compared to other methods).

Comment: I recommend you go with @AaronBertrand's suggestion and use [STUFF()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

Comment: Mostly this is a starting point for more complex recursive CTE expressions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Your link doesn't seem to work. For a performance site, they seem to be running really slow.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't know what was going on 7 hours ago but it seems to be working fine for me right now (and reviewing the logs I don't see any evidence of problems overnight).

Comment: Hmm, I'm interested to see what happens in the Scalar UDF approach when SQL Server decides to switch to parallel mode or otherwise process the records in an order that I'm not expecting.

Comment: @Jonathan that's exactly one of the reasons I don't recommend the UDF approach (even though I do document it in that article, because it's a common approach) - you can't control or rely on the order regardless of parallelism anyway. With FOR XML PATH, you *can* control and rely on the order.

Answer (score 0):

1. Number the counties by state (NumberedCounties)
2. Select the first county in each state (JoinedCounties, RowNumber = 1)
3. Select the second county in each state (JoinedCounties, RowNumber = RowNumber+1)
4. Get the max row numbers (WithMax)
5. Filter by the max row numbers
6. Make sure you are not exceeding your recursion limit.

.

```
   WITH    NumberedCounties(RowNumber, County, State)
              AS (SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.State ORDER BY c.County),
                            c.County,
                            c.State
                  FROM      Static.County C
                 ),
            JoinedCounties(RowNumber, Counties, State)
              AS (SELECT    RowNumber,
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), County),
                            State
                  FROM      NumberedCounties
                  WHERE     RowNumber = 1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT    C.RowNumber,
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), R.Counties + ', '
                            + C.County),
                            C.State
                  FROM      JoinedCounties R
                            INNER JOIN NumberedCounties C ON R.State = C.State
                                                             AND C.RowNumber = (R.RowNumber
                                                                  + 1)
                 ),
            WithMax(Counties, State, RowNumber, MaxRowNumber)
              AS (SELECT    Counties,
                            State,
                            RowNumber,
                            MAX(RowNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY State) AS MaxRowNumber
                  FROM      JoinedCounties
                 )
        SELECT  Counties,
                State
        FROM    WithMax
        WHERE   RowNumber = MaxRowNumber
    OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 500);
```

Note: If you have a non-trivial number of records, this is going to be really slow compared to concatenating it inside the application.

Comment: You could avoid the `WithMax` step by just adding a `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.State)` to `NumberedCounties`. But really, if you feel this can be useful despite the fact there are better concatenation methods, why don't you elaborate on why (as in "give an example where using this particular method is preferable").